# What kind of operation is cube root extraction?

Tags: functions, roots, relations, function-and-relation-composition, binary-operations

I came across this question in a random test and the correct answer was marked as "Binary Operation".
I am pretty sure that to find the cube root of a number you only need that number alone and so I thought it is a "Unary Operation".

After searching around the web, I could see many sites mention this question and the answer as "Binary Operation" but no one has an explanation for that.

Can anyone help me understand why it is a Binary operation or are these websites wrong?

Comment: It is as complicated or as simple as you wish for it to be.  If you want to define the symbol $\sqrt[3]{\square}$ where it requires a single input into the $\square$ then yes, it can be thought of as unary.  If you want to define the symbol $\sqrt[\square]{\square}$ where you require a separate input for the first and second boxes, where the first is specifying that we are talking about cubic roots rather than square roots or otherwise... then yes, it can be thought of as a binary operator.

Comment: What is "this question"? Do you have a screenshot of the wording? If the question asks "Let $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$. What type of operation is $f$", then yes, it is a unary function, since it takes one argument $x$.

Comment: This is example of a bad question, as the other comment mentioned it depend on how defined qube root is defined, once an idiot lecturer did not accept an answer that left the values in pi or roots , wanted them to be in numbers, all the course we were told not to use calculators and he used calculator! when not sure what the question is meant to say then you must force them to be clear

Comment: Thank you for your replies.
These are the exact thoughts I had in my mind when I encountered the question in a sample test paper released by a local educational institution. But I could find the same question in sites like [Toppr](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/extraction-of-a-cube-root-of-a-given-number-is/) and various other sites where they provide answers to test questions.
But I now believe that either the question is incomplete or the answers provided in these sites are wrong.
The actual question screenshot: https://ibb.co/nRNpXqr